# How to get the data from same table by different conditions in SQL without UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below data in my ColorAssign table;

```
| PKID | Name    | Type | HasAssigned |
| 11   | Red     | 1    | True        |
| 12   | Blue    | 2    | False       |
| 13   | Yellow  | 3    | False       |
| 14   | Red1    | 1    | False       |
| 15   | Yellow1 | 3    | True        |
| 16   | Blue1   | 2    | False       |
```

Note in this above table i have color types in type field and assignstatus in HasAssigned field also with different primary keys with different names(can be same name - but type is the identifier to find the actual color).

My goal is to get the data as the condition:- Find the records with the color type with Hasassigned = true or if no records for the type has true. Then type with Hasassigned = false of color type. So my resultset would be;

```
    | 11   | Red     | 1    | True        |
    | 12   | Blue    | 2    | False       |
    | 15   | Yellow1 | 3    | True        |
    | 16  | Blue1   | 2    | False       |
```

This would be possible with UNION by writing two queries, can we do this with one query. Looking for other optimized way?

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?

Comment: The description of your condition isn't clear. But, if I understand correctly, you want for each Type, either the color with HasAssigned = true or if no row for the Type has true, the one with HasAssigned = false. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes sloan, i'll Just update the condition in my question.

Comment: @giorgos I need this query for MSSQL. But here am looking for logic or any possiblity with joins. An optimized way.?

Comment: I think your best option is to use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to prioritize `True` records over `False` records. I tried to write a solution towards this option.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server you can use the following query:

```
SELECT PKID, Name, Type, HasAssigned
FROM (
   SELECT PKID, Name, Type, HasAssigned,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Type 
                       ORDER BY CASE WHEN HasAssigned='True' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rnk
   FROM ColorAssign) AS t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MJERQ92284)

Comment: Can we get the same result in other way using joins or something, i hope that would be more optimised then subquery...

Comment: @pvaju896 Did you give my query a try? Using window functions to prioritize is usually the most efficient method.

Comment: yes i tried its working perfect for me. But i was just curious to know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, the following should produce the result you asked for:

```
SELECT
    `PKID`,
    `Name`,
    `Type`,
    `HasAssigned`
FROM `ColorAssign`
GROUP BY `Type`
ORDER BY `HasAssigned` DESC;
```

Comment: This did not work for me, Order by and group by wount work together in a query in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this way, and i could get the result;

```
select * from ColorAssign ci where 
 (ci.HasAssigned = 'True'
 OR
 NOT EXISTS(select 1 from ColorAssign sc where sc.Type = ci.Type AND sc.HasAssigned = 'True' )
 )
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, an OR statement in the WHERE clause would do what you want:

```
WHERE (
        (Type = @Type AND HasAssigned = True)
        OR
        HasAssigned = False
       )
```

Comment: That won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: I will not pass a parameter like Type, Need to find records with all types by the query